# How to scan for words in Java excluding punctuation

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to use the scanner class to parse all the words in a file. The file contains common text, but I only want to take the words excluding all the puntuation.
The solution I have until now is not complete but is already giving me some problem:

```
Scanner fileScan= new Scanner(file);
String word;
while(fileScan.hasNext("[^ ,!?.]+")){       
    word= fileScan.next();
    this.addToIndex(word, filename);
}
```

Now if I use this on a sentence like "hi my name is mario!" it returns just "hi", "my", "name" and "is". It's not matching "mario!" (obviously) but it's not matching "mario", like I think it should.

Can you explain why is that and helping me find a better solution if you have one?
Thank you

Comment: What about something like `Dr. Mario's`?

Comment: How is `getNextWord` defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

import java.util.*;

```
class S {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileScan= new Scanner("hi my name is mario!").useDelimiter("[ ,!?.]+");
        String word;
        while(fileScan.hasNext()){       
            word= fileScan.next();
            System.out.println(word);
        }

    } // end of main()
}


javac -g S.java && java S
hi
my
name
is
mario
```

Comment: Because `next(pattern)` [returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern)). The last token (with default delimiters) is `"Mario!"`, which does not match `"[^ ,!?.]+"`

Comment: Thank you, now I understand next() much better!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get rid of the punctuation, you can simply replace all punctuation marks before adding to the index:

```
word = word.replaceAll("\\{Punct}", "");
```

In the case of hypens, or other isolated punctuation marks, you just check if `word.isEmpty()` before adding.

Of course, you'd have to get rid of your custom delimiter.

Comment: For the last token, `"mario!"`, `fileScan.hasNext("[^ ,!?.]+")` will return false. So `word.replaceAll("\\{Punct}", "");` will not be executed, correct? OP would still not get to Mario.

Comment: @Hemal Pandya - I meant to use the default separator - a space - not his custom one

Comment: It is not clear from your answer that not only `word.replaceAll()` is to be done but `fileScan.hasNext` has to be changed too. It would be nice if you can edit your answer, but I guess this comment exchange also clarifies that.